# How to hide a list element on linkbutton click within an asp listview control using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

I have a `asp:listview` control that is populating data from a databound data table in the code behind to create a dynamic list. With that list I have a linkbutton that I wish to bind to a JavaScript function to hide the corresponding `li` element if clicked. Here is my HTML:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstAIInsureds" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="collection">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
        </ul>                
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="collection-item" id="liRemoveAI">
            <div>
                <%#Eval("Response").ToString().Replace("|",", ")%>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbRemoveAI" class="material-icons" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return RemoveAI();" runat="server">remove_circle</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </li>   
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p>Nothing here.</p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and my code behind is being bound like so:

```
this.lstAIInsureds.DataSource = dt;
this.lstAIInsureds.DataBind();
```

Here is my current JS, but of course has gaps in the for loop which is what I need to accomplish:

```
 function RemoveAI() {
        var olsRemoveAI = document.getElementById("liRemoveAI"); //this is the ls that is to be hidden
        var obtRemoveAI = document.getElementById("lbRemoveAI"); //this is the linkbutton that is clicked to hide the parent ls element

        for (i = 0; i < olsRemoveAI.???.length; i++) {
            //if this button is contained in the parent li, mark the li as hidden:
            olsRemoveAI.style.visibility = "hidden";
            olsRemoveAI.style.display = "none";

            //else:
            olsRemoveAI.style.visibility = "visible";
            olsRemoveAI.style.display = "block";
        }

        return false;
 }
```

is this do-able? Assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since the element **lbRemoveAI** is running at "server", you need to see the HTML output of your page and get the final client ID, then update your javascript with that element ID.

Comment: But i need a solution that handles this in JS without a post-page load. If removing the runat server tag is needed to resolve this issue, that is fine. My objective is to collapse this control by clicking the remove button without a postback.

Comment: As stated in the button documentation here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx) you could use the property OnClientClick="string" where string is the name of the function in your JS.

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent element:

```
var buttonParent = document.getElementById("lbRemoveAI").parentElement;
```

Of course, this will return the div and not the li. It looks like you could simply remove the div and change some of your CSS, or you could use .parentElement twice.

[Read this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp), it's about .parentElement.

Then, you can use:

```
buttonParent.style.display = 'none';
```

Or, with jquery:

```
$(buttonParent).hide();
```

UPDATE:

here's the jQuery that will work. You should really be using a class, not an ID for the buttons. Using (this) will reference the exact button that was clicked. You probably don't want jQuery, but I don't know how to do it with plain JS off the top of my head. It should be easy to figure out how to change it if you can't use jQuery.

```
var obtRemoveAI = document.getElementById("lbRemoveAI");
$(obtRemoveAI).click(function() {
  $(this).parentElement.hide()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this in code, and this actually doesn't work for me unfortunately as i have a list of elements sharing the static id "lbRemoveAI". When the JS is executed, it correctly hides the parent of lbRemoveAI, but on subsequent executions it attempts to mark the same li item as hidden as it is only locating the first item in the list. What i need to do is be able to iterate through and determine what corresponding listbutton i pressed so the related li element gets hidden. Is this possible?

Comment: I updated my code to use the (this) variable to reference the actual button that was clicked.